# awaiting on an Event using IObserver Interface and AutoEventHandler/TaskCompletionSource

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, async-await, observer-pattern

In my scenario I am implementing an IObserver interface to poll for updates to a specific variable through a method. I have one thread that is created just to execute this method. This thread for now should never quit looking for updates to some data.

```
public static void findUpdates()
{
    while(true)
    {
        CheckForUpdates(); //registered to the observer
    }
}
```

I then have multiple threads coming into a class method to receive updates.

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool>updateHappened = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
object updatedValue;

public async Task receiveUpdates(){

    while(true)
    {
        await updateHappened.Task;
        //check to see if the thread cares about the updated value or not
        //update or do not update and possibly terminate
    }

}
```

and in the OnNext implementation

```
public void OnNext(Object value){
    updatedHappened.SetResult(true);
}
```

The reason I need to await an event is because when I have threads enter my while() loop is receiveUpdates if they are not awaited then there ends up being a max number of threads that can be scheduled and some threads get blocked from executing until another exits.

This is not behaving properly right now and it I can never get past the await updateHappened.Task; line no matter how many threads I create and send through to receive updates.

I would like the ability to have threads who want to receive updates come through, suspend execution in the threadpool waiting to be executed so that other threads (however many) can also try and receive updates, and then when a update happens resume each thread one at a time and update it or not before suspending it again. The one thread will always poll for updates using the IObserver interface but every other thread trying to receive updates will always continue to look for updates unless it exits under a condition.

Comment: This is strange. `await` should make the outer function to return the task and free the thread. I think the issue is in how you call `receiveUpdates`. Also did you check that  `OnNext` is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TaskCompletionSource<T>` can only be completed once; it's a single-shot signal, and that's it.

Since you're already using Rx, consider having the source thread expose its observable with `Publish` and `Connect`/`RefCount`. This will permit multiple subscribers to receive the same data. Then for the threads that just want to `await`, use `await sequence.FirstAsync()`.

Comment: Can you point me to an example of sequence.FirstAsync() or using await with Rx? Cannot find the .FirstAsync() method on a ISubject<> object

Comment: It's defined in `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable` - just make sure you have a recent Rx version.